# Insert sorted rows in another table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sort a database table and insert sorted rows into another table. However, when I query the new table, it still has unsorted data.

```
Create table #unsorted (ID int, dt date)
Insert into #unsorted values(1, '2019-01-01')
Insert into #unsorted values(2, '2018-12-15')
Insert into #unsorted values(3, '2017-01-01')

select * from #unsorted -- unsorted data as expected

Create table #sorted (ID int, dt date)

insert into #sorted 
select ID, dt from #unsorted Order by dt asc

select * from #sorted -- It should be sorted by date but it is not.
```

Expected Result of #sorted  table:

```
3   2017-01-01
2   2018-12-15
1   2019-01-01
```

Actual Result of #sorted  table:

```
1   2019-01-01
2   2018-12-15
3   2017-01-01
```

How can I physically sort data in the table when inserting into another table?

Comment: SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  There is no ordering in a result set unless an `order by` is explicitly used.

Comment: I see, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - the database will order a table's data however it likes when it comes to storing it (usually tables have a clustering key, and storage order is based on the value of the column(s) that form the key. If there is no clustering key, storage order is unpredictable) and even then storage order may have no bearing on output order depending on what operations the query carries out in its pipeline

Order the data when you query it

Choosing a suitable clustering key based on how you plan to use the table's data is something of an art in itself and something your DBA will ponder very carefully, wringing his hands at the devs that just lash a GUID primary key in and leave SQL Server to suffer :)

Comment: I see, I needed it because SQL doesn't allow order by in the cursor. I will create another post for the other problem. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, something of an XY problem I think - post the query that's giving trouble.. We can possibly help rewrite it to remove the need for a cursor (usually devs only think they need cursors because set-based thinking doesn't come naturally)

Comment: You CANNOT order a view.

Comment: Posted the original problem in another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287931/order-by-in-sql-cursor

Comment: This answer is highly misleading.  How the data is physically stored in the data pages is irrelevant to the ordering in a query.  There are simply no guarantees without an `order by`.

Comment: "however it likes" and "usually" is wrong: if you have a clustering key then it *will always* order the stored rows by that, this is the definition of a clustered index. But all that is obviously irrelevant to the query result without an `order by`

Comment: @charlieface you have misinterpreted what I said. "however it likes" means "row storage order is an internal implementation detail" and "usually" refers to it being the case that most devs end up creating a clustering key whether they realize it or not, so tables usually (in general) have one. It does not mean that "most of the time sql server will order by a clustering key but sometimes it will order by something else even when a clustering key is present".

Comment: @developer Offtopic, but Re: "SQL doesn't allow order by in the cursor" - of course it does.

Comment: @CaiusJard I suspected that is what you meant, but it's not clear to others, you should clarify it