# Order by in SQL Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert cumulative value (CV) into a column using cursor. I would like to calculate cumulative value (CV) order by a date (DT) column.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #unsorted (ID INT, DT DATE, CV INT)
INSERT INTO #unsorted VALUES(1, '2019-01-01', 0)
INSERT INTO #unsorted VALUES(2, '2018-12-15', 0)
INSERT INTO #unsorted VALUES(3, '2017-01-01', 0)

DECLARE @CurrentID INT
DECLARE @CV INT = 0
DECLARE c CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT ID FROM #unsorted FOR UPDATE OF CV

    OPEN c

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CurrentID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @CV = @CV + @CurrentID
        UPDATE #unsorted
        SET CV = @CV
        WHERE CURRENT OF c

        FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @CurrentID
    END

    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c
```

SQL server does not allow to change the `SELECT ID FROM #unsorted FOR UPDATE OF CV` statement to `SELECT ID FROM #unsorted ORDER BY dt ASC FOR UPDATE OF CV`.

It throws `The cursor is READ ONLY.` error.

Expected result:

```
ID  DT          CV
3   2017-01-01  3
2   2018-12-15  5
1   2019-01-01  6
```

Current result:

```
ID  DT          CV
1   2019-01-01  1
2   2018-12-15  3
3   2017-01-01  6
```

Please check the value of column CV.

How can I sort data before calculating cumulative value (CV)?

EDIT: One of the solutions is to declare DT column as primary key so it will keep the data sorted in the table. However, I think it is not the best option.

Comment: I suppose the *real* question is, why do you want to use a `CURSOR` at all here? SQL is a set based language; it excels at set based methods. A `CURSOR` is the complete opposite of that.

Comment: There are additional calculation inside the cursor so I would like to keep it as is. However, I agree it can be rewritten to avoid use of the cursor.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest that I could probably count the number of valid reasons for using a `CURSOR` on one hand, so getting rid of it is very likely the real solution here. If you explain what your real goal is, I don't doubt many of the users here could explain how to do the same task in a set based method.

Comment: "sort data before calculating cumulative value": What is the reason to sort values that you are going to cumulate?

Comment: It is part of an existing codebase and there are complex logic around this. It will require a lot of refactoring if I try to get rid of the cursor. I know it should still be refactored. If there is no other option then I guess will have to get rid of the cursor.

Comment: @developer no calculations require a cursor. What does the *actual* code do? You're adding data, so what does the order matter?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Luuk I will update the question to clarify the expected output.

Comment: @developer not just the expected output. Post the actual code and what you actually want to calculate. Obviously, you can't use a cursor. If you want a running total, you can do so with `SUM() OVER()` eg `sum(somevalue) over(order by somedate rows unbounded preceding) as runningtotal`

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I think it should work. I will give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` with  [OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-the-over-clause) to generate cumulative totals. In this particular case :

```
select ID, DT, sum(id) over(order by dt) AS CV
from unsorted 
order by dt
```

Produces :

```
3   2017-01-01  3
2   2018-12-15  5
1   2019-01-01  6
```

`OVER()` and analytic functions like `LAG` and `LEAD` can solve many problems that required cursors or complex solutions in the past. For example, `LAG() OVER...` can be used to find the difference between the current row in an ordered result set and the previous one, or detect value changes, making it easier to find ranges or gaps in a sequence